# How can i pass parameters from datagridview to an open or main form without opening new form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I was thinking how can i pass parameters using constructors from datagridview which is in another form to my main form without opening new one. here's my code

-----------Main form constructor----------------------------------------

```
 Public Sub New(customerID As Integer, fullName As String, phoneNumber As String, emailID As String)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    _customerID = customerID
    _fullName = fullName
    _phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    _emailID = emailID
End Sub
```

-----------------------------second form edit button click ----------------------------

```
 Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    Dim formMain As New frmMain(CInt(Me.dgvCustomerInfo.Item(0, Me.dgvCustomerInfo.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value),
                               Me.dgvCustomerInfo.Item(1, Me.dgvCustomerInfo.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value,
                               Me.dgvCustomerInfo.Item(2, Me.dgvCustomerInfo.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value,
                               Me.dgvCustomerInfo.Item(3, Me.dgvCustomerInfo.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value)
    Me.Hide()
    'formMain.Hide()
    formMain.Show()
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass the existing form as a parameter

Comment: Can you explain it how?

Comment: If you do nto want to open a new fporm, dont create a new form.  Create a method and pass the data

Comment: Can anyone show how? I am confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a property in your second form which is a list of the type of value that you want to pass and then when you create the form, assign your values to the property. Finally process the property using code in the form2.Shown event like this

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub test()
        Dim f2 As New form2
        f2.formparameters = {4, 5, 6, 7}
        f2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And in your 2nd form write something like this..

```
Public Class form2
    Friend Property formparameters() As Integer()

    Private Sub form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        'process parameter data here
        Me.Update()
    End Sub
End Class
```